# как сделать так чтобы выполнялось ровно одно условие

Tags: python, условия

Как сделать так, чтобы блок кода выполнялся при истинности только одно условия из нескольких?

Comment: @Akina автор имел в виду бытовое значение `или` (пример "`Пойдём в кино, к друзьям или в магазин`"), там подразумевается, что из перечисленных условий будет верно лишь одно.

Comment: @AivanF. Во блин... ни в жисть бы не догадался. Умеют же люди сформулировать...

Answer (score 5):

Например, есть переменные `a`, `b` и `c`, и надо, чтобы блок кода выполнился, если из условий `a == 3`, `b > 10` и `c % 5 == 0` выполняется ровно одно.

Одно.. Так давайте подсчитаем, сколько условий выполнилось, и проверим, что их сумма равна единице:

```py
a = 3
b = 14
c = 15

if (a == 3) + (b > 10) + (c % 5 == 0) == 1:
    print('Выполнилось ровно одно условие!')
```

Ведь результаты вычисления условий это значения типа `bool`, то есть, `True` или `False`, а они в арифметических операциях приводятся к 1 и 0, поэтому их можно легко считать.

Answer (score 0):

Arsen, возможно, вам подойдёт ***xor*** - исключающее ИЛИ.
Но, множество подобной информации находится в Googl-е, так что советую вам прибегать к его помощи почаще)

Comment: `xor` подойдёт, но только если условий 2. Если их больше, то **xor** даст истину, когда истинно нечётное число условий, например, 3 из 3.

Comment: Тогда можете посмотреть ответ от AivanF, там, по-моему, то, что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

```
if((condition1 == value1 and condition2 != value2) or (condition1 != value1 and condition2 == value2))
```

По-факту, просто проверь 2 своих условия отдельно друг от друга, если говорить псевдокодом :

```
Если значение 1 равно условию 1 и значение 2 не равно условию 2
ИЛИ
Если значение 1 не равно условию 1 и значение 2 равно условию 2
```

Comment: Вы просто расписали оператор **XOR** через `AND` и `OR`, получилось излишне громоздко.